# php $_get remove + from spaces

Tags: php, get

I am just starting this project and PHP is not my language (sorry if this is a stupid question! tried google but maybe I was searching for teh wrong thing).

I am trying to get data from a GET and eventually log it to a mysql database

the data will look like:
http://127.0.0.1/index.php?foo=1&hello+this+is+my+name=bob

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value){
    echo "Key: $key Val: $value<br>" ;
}
```

this will output:

```
Key: foo Val: 1
Key: hello_this_is_my_name Val: bob
```

of course this works fine but how can I remove the + signs or underscores from $key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` to replace underscores with spaces. Something like this :

```
echo str_replace('_', ' ', $value);
```

But of course, that will also replace the underscores that you might want to keep. Because of that, a better choice would be `urldecode()` function.

```
echo urldecode($value);
```

You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: I have tried echo urldecode($key); but it leaves the underscores

Comment: Oh Okay. That's because they are `$key` in the array. Superglobal arrays are decoded implicitly anyway. You'd have to go with `str_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php function  str_replace and after display output

```
<?php
echo str_replace("_"," ",$key);
?>
```

**Syntax**

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for removing underscore `(_)` and plus `(+)` sign from your string:

**Example String:**

```
$yourString = "This+is+my Testing_string_test";
$replace = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', ' ', $yourString );
echo $replace; // This is my Testing string test
```

This pattern `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/` will replace underscore and plus sign into space `' '`.